# Magento get Configurable option sort by min price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, frontend, sorting

I have created on configurable product A  with   attribute Unit  which contains  following Value:

Option A: 500$
  Option B:  300$
  Option C:  1500$

On the frontend, it's showing as drop-down line  Option A, Option B, and Option C.

I want to show Option B,  Option A, and Option C.    It should be sort by min price of the option.

Using Following code getting child product id but this is we want to sort by using super attribute pricing value.
$_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);

Is there any way we can sort the array bu super attribute pricing?

[image]

Is there any way we can sort by super attribute pricing on the frontend?

On the front it should display:

500ml X 6
24X 500ml

As per the above screenshot.